# Problems during last step of installing OpenSSL on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: openssl, macos-sierra

I am trying to install OpenSSL on my computer (macOS Sierra version 10.12.2). I downloaded openssl-1.1.0d.tar.gz from [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/) and followed the INSTALL manual included in it.

I followed the instructions for Unix systems, which were:

```
$ ./config
$ make
$ make test
$ make install
```

When running the tests I got `All tests successful` and `Result: PASS`. But when running `make install` I got the error message

```
Cannot create directory /usr/local/ssl: No such file or directory
make: *** [install_ssldirs] Error 2
```

And when looking in the /usr/local directory I can't find a directory called ssl, so I tried making one but it seems I didn't have permission to do it.

I have tried finding an answer by googling the error message but can't seem to find anything, and would really appreciate some help! The reason why I'm trying to download OpenSSL in the first place is because I'm taking a course in Computer Security and I need it for a project. Also, this is the first time I am posting a question here so if you're missing some information, please tell me!

EDIT: I noticed that there is a directory inside the openssl directory I downloaded called ssl, should I just move that to `usr/local/`? Would that solve my problem? (I know I sound like an idiot but I feel ready to try anything at this point)

Comment: Use `sudo  make install`. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki. If your machine is a 64-bit Intel, then you should consider `enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128` during configure. Diffie-Hellman can run upto 4x faster.

Comment: @jww Thank you! It worked :D

Comment: @jww I knew this (sude make install) was the solution, yet I still had to google it...lolz, THanks for the heads up.
why not post it as an answer? Or should I? and get the points? lolz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: @eloutie your question on Stack Overflow inspired the OpenSSL team to clarify the INSTALL instructions, see [pull request #9268](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/9268) on GitHub.